# Substring parsing within inconsistent text column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring

I have a text column that has a data value (int) within it that I need to parse out. The problem is that it is not in the same character column, so a simple `substring(x, 180, 5)` won't work as it sometimes will return a character as well.

The data value always comes after the phrase `'value received:'`.
Is it possible to parse the value out whereby SQL will take the next 3 values after this wording? Or even better, can you "catch" the value between two words? As before the value is a `:` and after the value there is always the word "complete".

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: When you say *"I have a text field"* do you mean it's the `text` datatype? If so, you should really change that; `text` has been deprecated for **16 years** and its use is strongly discouraged. Use `varchar(MAX)`.

Comment: hi, sorry the column is a varchar(500)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Please provide ##1-4 from the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
select substring(x, charindex('value received', x) + 14, 5)
```

Without sample data, this might be off by a character or two.

Comment: hi, thanks for that, apologies i should have mentioned, even the placement of the "values received"  is not always in the same place.  would there be a way to have the query to pull the data value between two texts, so it would go "value recieved :" then the data value we pull, then once the next string value is "complete" it stops?

Comment: You're going to probably need to nest substrings and charindex.  This first one will get you from 'value received:' to the end of you string. Then you can use charindex to find the position of 'complete', and use that for the length of your second substring.

Comment: @Git_Hub-96 . . . This uses `charindex()` to find where `'values received'` is.